How to reproduce workflow diagram myself via REST APIs
Here I have a simple workflow associated with my issue.

I want to know how I can obtain this workflow data programmatically via REST API. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueidorkey-transitions-get (/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions) is close to what I need. It shows me what transitions are available and any rules or conditions set. Unfortunately, this doesn't give me the complete picture I need. Given this example, if the issue is currently in "Open" and I were to call the API, I only see one entry in the response for "In Progress". I don't see "Done" listed. Likely because "Done" isn't a permissible transition until the issue has been moved to "In Progress".
So what API exists that allows me to look at all the transitions available? Essentially what I'd like to accomplish here is the ability to reproduce this workflow diagram as it's presented in jira for myself via the REST APIs.

Found out that endpoint https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-workflows/#api-rest-api-2-workflow-search-get (/rest/api/2/workflow/search) with the appropriate query parameters gives me what I need. I ended up going with https://{subdomain}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/workflow/search?expand=transitions,statuses&workflowName={workflowName}
